# Laravel send email no data

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with my Laravel app.
I'm trying to send an email, but any time it sends it's not sending details that I need to pass to view.
I'm trying like (view)

```
Hello <strong>{{ $order['title'] }}</strong>,
<p>{{ $order['body'] }}</p>
```

But title and body are empty.
This is how controller looks like:

```
$order = [
            'title' => 'title',
            'body' => 'test body'
        ];

        \Mail::to($user->email)->send(new OrderCreated($order));
```

And this is in mail

```
public $order;    
public function build()
        {
            return $this->subject('Order Created')->view('emails.order');
        }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you accepting the $order via a constructor and setting it on the mailable?

Comment: No, constructor is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not setting the `$order` property on your mailable.

You passing the order in when you do `\Mail::to($user->email)->send(new OrderCreated($order));` so you just need to accept and set it in your mailable:

```
public function __construct($order)
{
    $this->order = $order;
}
```

From there, the order will actually be accessible in your view as it is a public property.